# asp.net How to set textbox length based on dropdownlist selection? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, visual-studio-2012, code-behind

The drop down list contains three countries, How do you set the minimum number of digits to be entered in the postcode text-box based on what country is selected. 
For example, if user selects America, then the postcode text-Box should be set to "[0-9]{6}". But if they select Australia then the post code should be "[0-9]{4}".

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem  Value="-1">Country</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>America</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Australia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Sweden</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidateCountry"    
    initialValue="-1"
    ForeColor="Red" 
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Please choose Country" 
    ControlToValidate="dropDownList"/>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="PostCode"></asp:Label>
    <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:textbox>
    <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    OnServerValidate="TextValidate" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
    ErrorMessage="Invalid postcode.">
    </asp:CustomValidator>

    <asp:Button ID="BtnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the SelectedIndexChanged events of the dropdownlist. Set the AutoPostback to true in the dropdownlist write the similar described logic according to your need.

```
private void dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //your logic, something like that
    if(dropDownList.SelectedText =="America")
    {
       TextBox1.MaxLength= your value ...
    }
}

<asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostback = "true">
```

**EDIT:**
You can check the total number of character of textbox with your predefined value.

```
int minlength = 5;
if(textbox1.text.length < minlength)
{
   //Flag error on validation label
}
else
{
   //your stuff
}
```

Comment: I dont want to just set the max length... I want to set the min and max length.

Comment: I know the logic... i just dnt know the how to call it. Likw Maxlength is for maximum, but i cant find minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You also have client side events for the asp .net dropdown. You can set a javascript function to execute if the dropdown selection changes without posting back to the server. This will make the experience more streamlined and you can alter the min and max length directly with jquery.

You can do it like this:

```
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnSelectedIndexChange();")
```